# How to make my D3 lines Split?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick, nodes, show-hide

I have recently created a node map which has multiple nodes with line/arrows going between each node. I have recreated my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/GarrettUK/51j2rx1t/. I was wondering if anyone could show me how I could go about creating an on-click function on the lines so that when a line is clicked... 2 more lines are shown. So when its clicked we would have the line we just clicked in the middle and the 2 new lines either side.

I've already started creating the on-click function as seen in the example. I had a theory that you would create the 2 extra lines that connect to each node but have them hidden. Then when you click on the line. The function switches these lines from hidden to show.

My on-click function looks like this in the example:

```
.on("click", function(){
      // Determine if current line is visible
      var active   = redLine.active ? false : true ,
        newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
      // Hide or show the elements
      d3.select("#redLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
      // Update whether or not the elements are active
      redLine.active = active;
    });
```

Comment: I imagine it would be simply as you described-- only drawing the lines once some attribute allows it. You'd just want to have two additional lines for every connection, one with a slightly lower `dr` and one with a slightly higher number. You could then add some attribute to the lines to allow the `linkArc` function to know what radius it should be using.

Comment: Thanks! When I try to create another line it just breaks the lines altogether?

Comment: Could you possible show me how to do it in the Fiddler link?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xhpg2ghn/3/) Fiddle.